# Android App that does regex find-replace on clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard, regex, copy-paste

I'm looking for an Android App that I can set a matching regex pattern "like in [ClipRx](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dandalab.clipr)" for the frequently updated clipboard content. Once it finds a specific match, it applies the RegEx finds-replace sequence I've applied to that match.

This will be very helpful doing operations on text on the fly.

ClipRx only categorizes the clipboard log using Regex and it doesn't have the feature of adding RegEx replace operation to the matched text.

Notes:
Android version: 6
If no app doing this exists, I'm learning Java & Android to implement this idea in the future.

Comment: Did you manage to find such app? I'm interested as well